# Serialize field bypassing getter

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

How to use field value instead of getter due serialization with Jackson?

```
class Entity {
    public String value;

    Entity(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    @JsonIgnore // This makes field ignored too.
    public String getValue() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

So I want this code to return `{"value":"bar"}`, but it returns `{"value":"foo"}` without `@JsonIgnore`, and `{}` with it:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(entity);
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Coder in my real code there are coincided public field name from base class and `get...` method from interface. Add more info to example.

Comment: When you use @JSONIgnore you are implying to ignore the value attribute completely and hence the blank response when you use it. For the other case you are setting the getter function to return "foo' all the time and hence you are getting "foo" in the response. Besides that you don't have the setter function for the respective value. Correct me if I am wrong